# Evaluating a string to a command

Tags: strings

How do I construct a string in LaTeX (perhaps with variables) that calls the LaTeX macro with the corresponding name?

For example, say I have defined a comment as `\def\Comment1{Example text.}` and `\def\CommentText[#1]{\comment#1}` and I want `\CommentText[1]` to produce "Example text".

I am pretty sure the above does not work.

Is there any way to make it work? Is there some good way to achieve the same result with another method (assuming I have about 50 comments that I want to name with names that make them easy for others to understand).

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answers. Let me add that I did not really want to index the comments by integers (although I would like to have the option); I am more thinking of a case where I have the comments in a file indexed by "key words", where someone else not so knowledgeable in LaTeX can easily edit them. I will not be able to test until tomorrow, but I believe that the answers given covers this case as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}


\begin{document}
\expandafter\def\csname Comment1\endcsname{Example}
\newcommand\CommentText[1]{\csname Comment#1\endcsname}

Test:
\CommentText{1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would add that doing directly \def\Comment1{Example} does not define a macro `\Comment1`. Instead, it defines the macro `\Comment` and tells LaTeX that it has to be followed by `1` (indeed, names of control words only contain letters). Ulrike's method using `\csname ...\endcsname` allows to put almost anything inside the name of the macro. But you cannot write `\Comment1` in your text: it will need to be `\csname Comment1\endcsname`.

Comment: How about to use `\@namedef` and `\@nameuse` from LaTeX2e kernel instead of `\csname ...\endcsname`? It seems more clearly.

Comment: @Leo: or the `\csdef`, `\csuse` and related macros from `etoolbox`.

Answer (score 8):

If you really want to make a list of comments indexed by an integer, why not use the [arrayjobx](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/arrayjobx) package?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{arrayjobx}
\newarray\Comment
\Comment(1)={Example}
\Comment(42)={Another Example}

\begin{document}
\Comment(1)
\Comment(42)
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Ulrike's excellent answer could perhaps benefit from a little more macrology:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\newcommand\defComment[2]{\expandafter\def\csname Comment#1\endcsname{#2}}
\newcommand\CommentText[1]{\csname Comment#1\endcsname}
\begin{document}

\defComment{1}{Example}
\defComment{42}{Another example}

Test:
\CommentText{1} \CommentText{42}
\end{document}
```